# How to set value of a field of the selected row in SAP PowerBuilder detail window

Tags: powerbuilder

I wanted my project to hide/unhide column "**my_column**" of selected row at my detail data window. How can I achieve this. I am using SAP PowerBuilder 12.5. Below is my code:

```
this.modify("my_column_label.visible = true")
this.modify("my_column.visible = true")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DataWindow:

1º) For example, select the column: "my_column"

2º) In its properties, locate "Visible" and click on its button "=" of expression

[image]

3º) Enter the code that determines when it should be visible, for example:

```
IF (not IsNull (my_column), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Although I have made it this way before you answered my question, still thanks for the nice answer and also in order for others to be informed on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your detail datawindow has multiple rows.  The easiest way to do this is to modify the sql statement to return a computed column with the data set.  Syntax is similar to this:

```
,'' as selected
```

Then in the datawindow painter set up an expression on the visible property of the column.  Similar to:

```
if(selected[0] = 'Y', 1, 0)
```

Then in the clicked or rowfocuschanged event on the datawindow you set the value of 'selected' to 'Y' or 'N' depending upon if the row is selected or not,  Remember setting something invisible does not mean it is protected, that is a separate property.